# send whatsapp message from angular 2 web app

Tags: angular, whatsapp

Building a web app using angular 2, (or 4). Want to send a message through whatsapp. This works fine `whatsapp://send?text=hi!` to open whatsapp from the browser. I want to send the url of the current page. I can use {{url}} to print the url on the web page but I don't know how to set text={{url}} if you know what I mean.

relevant part of the component `

```
export class ActivityDetailsComponent implements OnInit {


  @Input() activity: any;
  @Output() close = new EventEmitter();
  error:any;
  navigated = false;
  sub: any;
  imageURL: string;
  location:Location;
  url: any;

  constructor(private activitiesService:ActivitiesService,
                private route: ActivatedRoute,
                private router: Router,
                private pics: PicsService,
                location:Location             

                ) { 

                this.location = location;
                this.url = this.location.path();

                 }
```

`

relevant html 
`

```
    Send a link to this activity to your
     <a href="whatsapp://send?text=http://ec2-52-209-95-130.eu-west-  
 1.compute.amazonaws.com:4200/activities/58c003d47513092fac820f09">whatsapp</a>
     contacts  

    http://ec2-52-209-95-130.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:4200{{url}}
```

`

Comment: copy the URL and past it wherever you want

Comment: Where do you get access to the `url` variable?

Comment: @Amit I've hard coded the www.example.com part and used `this.url = this.location.path();` to get the 'pageID' part

Comment: @RameshRajendran I want the user to be able to share the page in whatsapp by just clicking the link

Comment: Can you post your component's code and template?

Comment: @Amit edit above

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible techniques to solve your problem:

1. [Property binding](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#property-binding)

We use square brackets to tell angular to resolve the value of the href field. Additionally we use simple string concatenation:

```
<a [href]="'http://example.org/?test=' + url">whatsapp</a>
```

2. [Interpolation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#interpolation)

This is technique uses the curly brackets and is the one you tried to use:

```
  <a href="{{'http://example.org/?test=' + url}}">whatsapp</a>
```

In your case you can chose the solution you prefer, the official documentation (same link as above) states the following:

> When rendering data values as strings, there is no technical reason to
>   prefer one form to the other. You lean toward readability, which tends
>   to favor interpolation. You suggest establishing coding style rules
>   and choosing the form that both conforms to the rules and feels most
>   natural for the task at hand.

Comment: What do you want to address with your comment ?

Comment: that's the whatsap code, ` text=`  is not able to translate {{url}}

Comment: You can replace the url (example.org) above with any String you like. If you use on of the shown snippets the value of url will be appended to the previous String.  And what do you mean with translate?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to do it

```
var url = document.URL var red = (url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('=') + 1)); window.location.replace("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=" + red);
```

Or you can use the permanent link below to go directly without any script

> [https://www.educlick.page/p/whats-app-redirect.html?url>url encode<](https://www.educlick.page/p/whats-app-redirect.html?text=Educlick.page)